# Bad output for "npm ls"

Tags: node.js, debian-wheezy, console, npm

How can I fix this ugly output for "npm ls"?

[image]

Debian Wheezy / node v0.10.36 / npm 2.4.1

**UPDATE:**

«*» - is an ugly char, that I can not reproduce here:

```
helloworld@1.0.0 /var/www/helloworld
  *** express@4.11.2
  *** accepts@1.2.3
    ***** mime-types@2.0.8
    ***** mime-db@1.6.0
      ****** negotiator@0.5.0
```

Comment: Instead of linking to an image, please include the text of the output in your post.  Then the post will still be useful in future when the image goes away.  If there are characters that you can't reproduce, put something in their place and tell us what happened.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Generally yes, but sometimes (like here) that's just not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed Putty encoding to UTF-8 and the problem was solved.